# Cannot find database instance in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

I've made an Amazon AWS account to use their DB services (SQL Server in specific). However when connecting to the server, it does not show my DB instance, it only contains "System databases", "Database snapshots" and "rdsadmin".

[image: Amazon aws SQL server instance]

[image: List of databases]

Comment: Create a database.

Comment: I. feel. stupid. THANKS